# MySQL - create database backup gives me error 1064

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create db create script on the VPS server (on Windows). But, the following command

```
mysql> mysqldump -u myuser -pmypass --complete-insert mydb_name > c:\file.sql;
```

gives me the error:

```
ERROR:
Unknown command '\f'.
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'mysqldump -u myuser -pmypass --complete-insert mydb_name >c:\file.sql' at line 1
```

The windows account is `guest`. Is it a must for that account to be `administrator` ? How to fix that error ?

### edit

when I try to execute that command from the Windows shell, I get the `access denied` error

Comment: `access denied` is not `mysql` database error but `file access error` on the OS. Check with your system admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should launch the `mysqldump` command from the OS command prompt, while you're attempting to run it as if it were a `mysql` command.

Plus, the `access denied` error is most likely due to you being on Windows 7 (or newer) and being a standard user, which (for a good reason) has no permission to create files in `C:\`.

You should try that same command from your home dir (e.g. `C:\Users\<username>`)

Answer (score 0):

`\` is treated as an escape character.

Use `/` instead.

Change:

```
c:\file.sql
```

To:

```
c:/file.sql
```

And you need to run `mysqldump` at shell prompt.

As per documentation at [mysqldump — A Database Backup Program](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html):

> mysqldump requires at least the SELECT privilege for dumped tables,
>   SHOW VIEW for dumped views, TRIGGER for dumped triggers, and LOCK
>   TABLES if the --single-transaction option is not used. Certain options
>   might require other privileges as noted in the option descriptions.
>
> To reload a dump file, you must have the same privileges needed to
>   create each of the dumped objects by issuing CREATE statements
>   manually.